# Android. Align xml-layout view according view created from code

Tags: android, layout, dynamic, addition

I create a button from code and places it on bottom of rootView

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams buttonParams = new  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    buttonParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    rootView.addView(getSaveButton(), buttonParams);
```

In xml layout I have a list that height = wrap_content. I want align list bottom with button top when button is created.

```
<ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/episodes_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/show_status_buttons_layout"
        android:groupIndicator="@drawable/indicator"
        />
```

How I can add android:layout_above="@id/button_save" layout parameter to ListView?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
buttonParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, R.id.button_save);
```

Comment: Ah it was a typo. Welll it seems you already figured it out. So set the answer so this question is removed from te unanswered list.

Answer (score 0):

```
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams listParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    listParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, getSaveButton().getId());

    episodesList.setLayoutParams(listParams);
```